# The difference of the principal point x coordinates in right and left images after rectification is large

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration, stereo-3d

The difference of the principal point x coordinates in right and left images after rectification in stereo imaging is about 10. The length of baseline is 10mm. The resolution of the left and right images is 800x600.

Isn't the difference large for the setup? What reasons may cause this difference?

In the book Learning OpenCV, it only reads that the difference will be 0 if the principal rays intersect at infinity, but doesn't mention the reasons.

**Edit:**
Cx should be equal to Cx'.
[image]

Comment: The principal point (cx,cy) should be an intrinsic parameter of each camera, isn't it? Do you mean the center of one image and the corresponding point in the other?

Comment: In stereo imaging, the position of  principal point x coordinates in two images should be same after rectification. If the difference of the positions is 0, it means that the principal rays intersect at infinity. I hope to know what can cause the difference.

Comment: I add one image to give more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the notation you add, you are referring to the Q matrix generated by `Stereorectify()` . [As the documentation says](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#stereorectify)

> where T_x is a horizontal shift between the cameras and cx_1=cx_2 if
>   CV_CALIB_ZERO_DISPARITY is set.

So you can force the two parameters to be equal with the proper flag, but the cause could be retrieved in the angle between the two cameras.

cx = cy when the 2 image plane are coplanar (principal rays intersect at infinity = principal rays are parallel). In this case, 
Z = f*T/d

If principal rays are convergent, W is increased by the term 
(cx -cx')/T so, even with disaparities d equal to zero, the point is not mapped at the infinity.

Comment: If the focal lengths of the two camera are a little different, what will happen?

Comment: @JoggingSong this is a too general question. Focal length in the 2 cameras are always a little different. I suppose you are asking in terms of consequences in points reprojection: I think that points are reprojected with respect to the reference system of one camera only, the should have different coordinates in the other reference system

Comment: I agree. The focal lengths will be a little different. How much difference is tolerant for one application? What will the difference cause? Can I use other methods to reduce the effect caused by the difference of two focal lengths? I am new to camera calibration.  There are many factors which will affect the final calibration accuracy. How can I evaluate these factors?

Comment: I can tell you about 2 factors: one is that calibration is a numerical minimization. The other is that the numbers fx, fy in camera matrix are the product of the actual focal length in mm and the pixel aspect ratios (effective dimensions of pixels can likely vary). I think (not sure) there are flags in OpenCV that can force your stereo-calibration to have the same values f.